# why doesn't Ext.form.field.disable automatically revalidate

Tags: extjs

```
    var bFoo = foo === "true";
    cmp.setDisabled(!bFoo ); //disabled always passes validation
    cmp.validate();
```

why doesn't Ext 3.3 call validate, or clearInvalid, for us in Ext.form.field.disable() ?

when the field is disabled, the invalid-style incorrectly lingers until the field is next validated. I think it should always validate immediately, or clear the style.

this also happens with enable() on a field with allowBlank=false; the disabled-style goes away, but the invalid-style doesn't appear until the user clicks, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Because `disabled` fields aren't submitted, so it doesn't matter if they're valid. Also, because `disabled` fields are disabled, the (non-programmer) user can't change the invalid value(s).

Comment: but the sawtooth incorrectly remains. if it doesn't call validate(), then it should call clearInvalid

Comment: Disabling a field is _logically_ separate from validation. So, it's not surprising that disabling a field (with really just adds the `disabled` attribute) doesn't clear any validation feedback. As far as I know, you'll just have to `clearInvalid` manually (though take that with a grain of salt, since I'm much more experienced with jQuery than Ext).

Comment: Disabling is indeed logically separate from validation but I think it's irritating to see a disabled field that is as well marked as invalid. Especially because the user can't do anything about it until the field becomes valid again. I agree with OP, when the field is disabled it shouldn't bug you with being highlighted in red or something else. I understand disabled state broadly, and this includes "disabling any validation logic". But it must be that have a different opinion...